# Save extracted video frames as images

Tags: matlab, image-processing, video-processing

I wish to take a screen grab of a video frame and save each frame as an image in a folder on my desktop. There are only certain frames I want to capture however, which are written in a text document.

My question is, how do I read in the frame numbers stored in this text document and only extract these frames to png files?

Thanks for any help you can provide. If I need to clarify anything, please ask.

```
frames = dlmread('Frames.txt');

%getting no of frames
numFrames = mov.NumberOfFrames;

%setting current status of number of frames written to zero
numFramesWritten = 0;

for t = frames: numFrames
   currFrame = read(mov, t);    %reading individual frames
   opBaseFileName = sprintf('%3.3d.png', t);
   opFullFileName = fullfile(opFolder, opBaseFileName);
   imwrite(currFrame, opFullFileName, 'png');   %saving as 'png' file
   progIndication = sprintf('Wrote frame %4d of %d.', t, numFrames);
   disp(progIndication);
   numFramesWritten = numFramesWritten + 1;
end
```

Comment: What code do you already have? What is the format of your text document?

Comment: The code I am trying to modify is a for loop that extracts every frame as a png file. I will add it to the body of my question above. The text document is simply one column of numbers. I can get the extract to start with the first number in the text document, but it just increments by one thereon. I'm unsure how to correctly run through these numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly:

> ... how do I read in the frame numbers stored in this text
>   document and only extract these frames to png files?

and assuming that 'frames' is a vector that contains the subset of indicies of the frames you want, then all you need to do is change the for loop

```
for t = frames
```

Comment: I get the following error when I try this:
"Frame Range must be a 1x2 vector of frame indexes with the first value less than or equal to the second value.
A Frame index must be a numeric value greater than zero and less than or equal to the number of frames in the file."
frames is of class double, upon checking in Matlab, Is this the issue? Thanks.

Comment: This occurs when I try to read the video. `currFrame = read(mov, t);`

Comment: can you try transposing t?

    for t = frames'

Comment: It works perfectly now, and so simple! Thanks a lot!